# Ubuntu 23.10 wifi adapter not found

Tags: networking, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 23.10.  Wifi was working for a while then disconnected.  I can not reconnect it even after rebooting.  When I click on either of my wifi connection in settings, settings switches to the Network tab.

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c123]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c123]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
```

Wifi works perfectly on 22.04

Is there a way to get the wifi working again.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04.

I fixed it by switching to an older kernel that was available in GRUB boot menu - 6.2

See [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

My network adapter:

```
➜  ~ lspci | grep net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```